# WPF Not sure how to change background of textbox in dynamically created stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, background, stackpanel

In a WPF project, I have a stackpanel...

```
<StackPanel Name="spOptionsValue" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="10 0 0 0"  KeyUp="SaveTestOptionsInXMLData2"></StackPanel>
```

That I dynamically load values into...

```
spOptionsValue.Children.Add(new TextBox { Text = attributeChild.Value, Height = 26, Name = "tbTestAttributeValue" });
```

If I find an error in the value of this textbox (after the user changes it), how can I make the background red and put the focus on this textbox?

When I try something like `spOptionsValue.Children[loopIndex - 3] = Brushes.Red;`  I get a compiler error of "Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush` to `System.Windows.UIElement`. I've also tried to work background into this statement without luck.  Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
((Control)spOptionsValue.Children[loopIndex - 3]).Background = Brushes.Red
```

The cast is necessary since `UIElement` has no Background property.

As for the focus, you would use:

```
((Control)spOptionsValue.Children[loopIndex - 3]).Focus();
```